# Why does Visual FoxPro not give the expected answer for certain comparisons?

Tags: comparison, visual-foxpro

The following behaviour from Visual FoxPro puzzles me.

```
CREATE TABLE test_17 (A C(2), B N(10,2))

CREATE TABLE test_18 (A C(2), B N(20))

INSERT INTO test_17 values ('C1', 1037.60)

INSERT INTO test_17 values ('C2', 2411.50)

INSERT INTO test_18 VALUES ('C1', 1037600)

INSERT INTO test_18 VALUES ('C2', 2411500)
```

The following query

```
SELECT * FROM test_17 a, test_18 b WHERE a.A = b.A AND a.B*1000 = b.B
```

only returns the **C2** line and not the **C1** line whereas:

```
SELECT * FROM test_17 a, test_18 b WHERE a.A = b.A AND a.B*1000 <> b.B
```

returns **nothing** as expected and

```
SELECT IIF(a.B*1000 = b.B,'T','F') FROM test_17 a, test_18 b WHERE a.A = b.A
```

returns **T**, 'T' as expected.

Can someone please explain to me why **Visual FoxPro** behaves this way? Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and put your queries in the `code` format, instead of "quote" format. They're easier to read that way.

Comment: Weird.  It misbehaves when SQL is involved, but not basic VFP commands.  "? test_17.b*1000 = test_18.b" returns .T. for each record, as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Try 
        int(a.B*1000) = b.B

In all digital devices, floating point numbers are an approximation, comparisons of them are just a guess.

Comment: correct, you would have to ROUND() the answer to a specific decimal precision